# Por qué no abre mongo compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Acabo de instalar mongodb version 5 todo bien, incluido el compass, pero al momento de ejecutar compass no abre, en el power shell, normal puedo ver la version y todo instalado, tambien ya tengo configurado en el path.

Gracias por su respuesta y ayuda.

Comment: Supongo que estás en Windows. Puedes ver si hay algo en el Visor de Eventos de Windows relacionado con el problema al iniciar Compass? En el administrador de tareas puedes ver si se inicia la aplicación? Probaste reiniciar antes de ejecutarlo?

Comment: Sí todas esas, y nada, no se a que se debe

Comment: Complicado adivinar sin más datos :/